# Ruby on Rails 4 - Paperclip AWS Image URL is wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4

I've used paperclip and AWS together before, but I just created this Rails 4 app, and my image.url method is showing looking for the image at 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/',  when it should be looking for them at 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'.  I'm assuming this is because the region for the first account is US Standard, whereas the new one is Oregon.

Any way for me to change the region in the config files or something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently there used to be a bunch of workarounds for this, but now there is an option in the config called s3_host_name.

```
ExampleApp:Application.configure do

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => '#',
      :access_key_id => '#',
      :secret_access_key => '#'
    }
  }

end
```