# Rails Paperclip returning wrong Cloudfront URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, amazon-cloudfront

I'm working on a Rails website that uses Paperclip to upload files to Amazon S3 and then serve them through Cloudfront. I've got the uploading working fine, and Cloudfront is serving the files properly, but for some reason `ModelObj.attachment.url` isn't working properly on my production server. It works fine on my development server (WEBrick under Windows 8) but is returning the wrong URL on the live site (LAMP with Phusion Passenger). It returns *almost* the right url, but instead of

```
http://[stuff].cloudfront.net/kidbooks/snds/5072_original.mp3?1393858446
```

I'm getting

```
http:///kidbooks/snds/5072_original.mp3?1393858446
```

It's configured as follows: In `environment.rb`:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => APP_CONFIG['s3_bucket'],
  :path => "/#{APP_CONFIG['s3_path']}/:attachment/:id_:style.:extension",
  :s3_credentials => {
    ...
  }
})
```

And in the model:

```
has_attached_file :snd,
  :url => ':s3_alias_url',
  :s3_host_alias => APP_CONFIG['cloudfront_domain']
```

`APP_CONFIG` is being set properly on both servers; I've checked. (Or at least, it's being set properly in the console on the live server; I guess I could check more directly. There doesn't *appear* to be anything relevant in `environments/development.rb` or `production.rb`. What's going wrong here, and how can I fix it?

(I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149815/ruby-on-rails-4-paperclip-aws-image-url-is-wrong), which is close to what I need, but only involves S3.)

**Update:** Found something weird. `Model.snd.options` returns a hash that includes, among other things, :s3_host_alias=>nil. Maybe my model is somehow being loaded before my configuration files?

Comment: What is the value of `APP_CONFIG['cloudfront_domain']` in the production server?

Comment: @Agis: `1.9.3-p429 :001 > APP_CONFIG['cloudfront_domain']`
 `=> "[correct].cloudfront.net"`. I guess it's possible that it's somehow different between the server and the console, but I don't know an easy way to test that (short of adding a dummy page somewhere).

Comment: What is the value of `APP_CONFIG['s3_path']`?

Comment: @Agis: Depending on the server, either `"kidbooks"` or `"kidbooks_dev"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, found it. For some reason my model is either being loaded before my config files, or the loader doesn't have access to `APP_CONFIG`. This meant that `:s3_host_alias` was being set to nil, which of course broke things. I moved `:s3_host_alias => APP_CONFIG['cloudfront_domain']` from the model to `environment.rb`, and now it's working fine.

I have no idea why my model would be loading before my config files, though.