# How to fix S3_url_path helper for paperclip in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to attach avatars to users in rails 5 using Paperclip 5.1.0 and S3. It seems that S3 has changed their URL style for retrieving images and I need to patch for that. Currently:

```
@user.avatar.url # => //s3.amazon.com/BUCKETNAME/path
```

and I need it to be

```
//BUCKETNAME.s3.amazon.com/path
```

Where is the best place for me to modify this, and how should I do it? Should I try and patch the module itself? I know it uses a helper called `s3_url_path` but I couldn't find it to try and edit it. Should I fix it in my controller on the way out of the model? Or should I try in fix it in the view? Where is the best place?

Comment: Looks like there is an option in the config called s3_host_name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149815/ruby-on-rails-4-paperclip-aws-image-url-is-wrong

Comment: That option is not available in Paperclip 5.1.0.

Comment: Looks like it is discussed at https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2237#issuecomment-270316533 and can be set with  s3_credentials: {    s3_host_name: "host_name_here" }